# How do I find an unknown flight reservation number?

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I have lost my flight reservation number. I think it's for frontier airlines. All I have is the dates I reserved. I don't know which site I used to book it.

Answer (score 15):

Call the airline.  They should be able to find your reservation by your name and travel dates.

Comment: Usually your name and specific flight and date are needed.

Comment: In my experience, the city pair should be sufficient, unless your name is very common.

Answer (score 7):

Check your credit card statement to find the website you used to book it and then contact them.

Answer (score 1):

Call Frontier Airlines at 801 401 9000.
Wait for someone to answer. Tell them your name  and they will ask Airport/Date/Time.

They will ask you for your email **and they may ask for last 4 digits of your credit card**. You will get an email with your confirmation number.